# In Mage_Customer what role does <fieldsets> have?

Tags: magento

I am just curious if the `<customer_account>` tag in `<fieldsets>` has any role or was used in older versions of Magento. As I can see, when creating a customer, the attributes are added to customer model from `customer_form_attribute` table using `$customerData = $customerForm->extractData($this->getRequest());` and `$customerForm->compactData($customerData);`

I know that in other modules are used, but for customer I can't find it's usefulness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally `<fieldsets>` are a part of the very useful [`copyFieldset`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Helper_Data.html#copyFieldset) function.  I find myself working with them almost every day.

Specifically, in `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection` there is this function:

```
/**
 * Add Name to select
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection
 */
public function addNameToSelect()
{
    $fields = array();
    $customerAccount = Mage::getConfig()->getFieldset('customer_account');
    foreach ($customerAccount as $code => $node) {
        if ($node->is('name')) {
            $fields[$code] = $code;
        }
    }

    $adapter = $this->getConnection();
    $concatenate = array();
    if (isset($fields['prefix'])) {
        $concatenate[] = $adapter->getCheckSql(
            '{{prefix}} IS NOT NULL AND {{prefix}} != \'\'',
            $adapter->getConcatSql(array('LTRIM(RTRIM({{prefix}}))', '\' \'')),
            '\'\'');
    }
    $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{firstname}}))';
    $concatenate[] = '\' \'';
    if (isset($fields['middlename'])) {
        $concatenate[] = $adapter->getCheckSql(
            '{{middlename}} IS NOT NULL AND {{middlename}} != \'\'',
            $adapter->getConcatSql(array('LTRIM(RTRIM({{middlename}}))', '\' \'')),
            '\'\'');
    }
    $concatenate[] = 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{lastname}}))';
    if (isset($fields['suffix'])) {
        $concatenate[] = $adapter
                ->getCheckSql('{{suffix}} IS NOT NULL AND {{suffix}} != \'\'',
            $adapter->getConcatSql(array('\' \'', 'LTRIM(RTRIM({{suffix}}))')),
            '\'\'');
    }

    $nameExpr = $adapter->getConcatSql($concatenate);

    $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('name', $nameExpr, $fields);

    return $this;
}
```

The first part of which essentially matches this XML:

```
<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <customer_account>
            <prefix>
                <create>1</create>
                <update>1</update>
                <name>1</name>
            </prefix>
            <firstname>
                <create>1</create>
                <update>1</update>
                <name>1</name>
            </firstname>
            <middlename>
                <create>1</create>
                <update>1</update>
                <name>1</name>
            </middlename>
            <lastname>
                <create>1</create>
                <update>1</update>
                <name>1</name>
            </lastname>
            <suffix>
                <create>1</create>
                <update>1</update>
                <name>1</name>
            </suffix>
        </customer_account>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

...and so the exact role of the `<customer_account>` tag is to specify which attributes to load when concatenating customer names.